# Xubuntu hangs on boot screen

Tags: boot, xubuntu, live-usb

I've recently been trying to install Xubuntu on my older laptop but i've been having some problems. Whenever I try to boot from my usb, it makes it to the loading screen with the spinning circle but after a little while, it just stops. I've tried using xubuntu 19.04 as well as 19.10 and the problem still persists.

Comment: The first think I would do is run the 'check disc for defects' to ensure your ISO was downloaded & written to your install media correctly. (the Lubuntu documentation shows it in first screen - https://manual.lubuntu.me/1/1.3/installation.html, though on some boxes you have to hit a key to get the menu to display on xubuntu [hardware specific]).  If that shows no issues then I'd think about what video hardware was in your unstated box, but check install media would be my first step.

Comment: @guiverc I ran the test and it said no errors were found.